# Why is it necessary for async method to have await

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

We use async keyword to make a method asynchronous. If the method does not use any await keyword, then the compiler generates the warning that the method will run synchronously. But I do not understand why this is so.
Let us assume that method f() calls method g() and f does not need to wait for g to complete. This means f needs to call g asynchronously. But such a requirement may arise even if g does not need to use any await. How will this be achieved?

Comment: without `await` exception that are thrown from the `async` method will be swallowed and never surface outside the method

Comment: All that `async` does is change *what version of C# you can write in the body of the method*. Specifically, it allows you to use `await`. It's the `await` part that is "magic".

Comment: `await` allows you to return to a fired `Task`.

Comment: "How will this be achieved?" - Actually async/await is the wrong tool to fire&forget. You can use Task.Run to have smoething be executed on the ThreadPool or you can enqueue a UserWorkItem directly.

Comment: However, if you are in ASP.Net, read this blog post by Stephen Cleary: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html

Answer (score 1):

> Let us assume that method f() calls method g() and f does not need to wait for g to complete.

Are you sure? "Fire and forget" literally means *forget*. I.e., you seriously don't care at all if `g` never completes, and you're OK with all exceptions from `g` being silently swallowed. That's what "fire and forget" actually means, and >90% of the time it's *not* what people really want.

> This means f needs to call g asynchronously.

And the way it does so is via `await`:

```
async Task f() => await g();
```

Answer (score -1):

For your purpose you can use Task.Run or Task.Factory.Start to fire and forget your method *g*:

```
void f() {
    ...
    Task.Run(() => g())
    ...
}
```

When calling an *async* method that doesn't apply the *await* operator it starts as asynchronous task. As no await operators are applied inside this method, the program continues without waiting for the task to complete. (see [Compiler Warning (level 1) CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014))

Comment: Watch out if this is in ASP.Net. See my comment to the question (the one with the link to Stephen C.'s blog).

Comment: This is pointless.  Adding `Task.Run` has done nothing for you. You could already have exactly the same behavior by just writing `g();`.